# Angular 5 - How to fill a FormArray

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I will fill the customerNumberContainers which looks like this:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({    
    customerNumberContainers: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        contactTenant: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
        customerNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])
        }),
    ]),
```

Therefore I do this after I get the values over

```
this.contactService.findContactById(this.id).subscribe(response => { ...
```

Set values into form:

```
let customerNumberContainersFormArray: FormArray = this.form.controls.customerNumberContainers as FormArray;
customerNumberContainersFormArray.controls["0"].controls.contactTenant.value = 'TestValue';
```

but it is not shown with:

```
in Controller:
get customerNumberContainers(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("customerNumberContainers") as FormArray;
  } 

in Template:
<div formArrayName="customerNumberContainers">
    <div *ngFor="let customerNumberContainer of customerNumberContainers.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">
        <input matInput formControlName="contactTenant">
    </mat-input-container> 
</div>
```

Does anyone known what I am doing wrong. It seems for me that values with *ngFor arn't refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

why dont You just patch whole form with model ? like this:

set up your model, for example:

```
export class Tenants {
  id: number;
  customerNumberContainers: TenantContact[];
}
export class TenantContact {
  contactTenant: string;
  customerNumber: string;
}
```

fetch it from service like u always do but it should match above models and patch whole form (or setValue)

```
this.contactService.findContactById(this.id).subscribe((tenats: Tenants) => {
      this.form.patchValue(tenats);
     });
```